# Axios put request not working yet no errors in console while delete, post and get request still works (React Js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am trying to make the update functionality works through the put request. All the other functionalities like get, delete and post works. When I tried to update the info by clicking the *add* button, the code in `App.js`, '*name* is already added to phonebook, replace the old number with a new one ?', still runs but nothing changes. No errors yet the data remains the same. I am wondering where did I do wrong ? The following are the `put` method code in index.js (backend), App.js and persons.js (both in the frontend).

index.js

```
// Add new person 
app.post('/api/persons', (request, response) => {
    const body = request.body
    
    const person = new Persons({
        name: body.name,
        number: body.number
    })

    person.save().then(savedPerson => {
      response.json(savedPerson)
    })
    // persons = persons.concat(person)
    // response.json(person)
})

// Edit person info
app.put('/api/persons/:id', (request, response, next) => {
  const body = request.body
  const existingPerson = persons.find(person=> person.name === body.name)

  const person = {
    name: body.name,
    number: body.number
  }

  if (!body.name || !body.number) {
    return response.status(400).json({ 
      error: 'name and number must be filled in' 
    })
  } else if (existingPerson) {
      window.confirm(`${existingPerson} already exist in the phonebook, continue to update phone number?`);
      Persons.findByIdAndUpdate(request.params.id, person, { new:true })
        .then(updatedPerson => {
          response.json(updatedPerson)
        })
        .catch(error => next(error))
  }
})
```

App.js

```
const addName = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const nameObject = {
      name: newName,
      number: newNumber
    }

    const changeNumberText = 'is already added to phonebook, replace the old number with a new one ?'
    const existingPerson = persons.find(person => person.name === nameObject.name)
    
    if (existingPerson && window.confirm(`${existingPerson.name} ${changeNumberText}`)) {
      personService
        .update(existingPerson.id, nameObject)
        .then(response => {
          setPersons(persons.map(person=>person.id === existingPerson.id ? response.data : person))
          setNewName('')
          setNewNumber('')
          setErrorMessage(
            `${existingPerson.name}'s phone number has been updated`
          )
          setTimeout(() => {
            setErrorMessage(null)
          }, 5000)
        })
    } else if(!existingPerson) {
      personService
        .create(nameObject)
        .then(response => {
          setPersons(persons.concat(response.data))
          setNewName('')
          setNewNumber('')
          setErrorMessage(
            `${nameObject.name}'s has been added to the phonebook`
          )
          setTimeout(() => {
            setErrorMessage(null)
          }, 5000)
        })
      }
  }
```

persons.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
const baseUrl = '/api/persons'

const getAll = () => {
  return axios.get(baseUrl)
}

const create = newObject => {
  return axios.post(baseUrl, newObject)
}

const update = (id, newObject) => {
  return axios.put(`${baseUrl}/${id}`, newObject)
}

const deletePerson = (id) => {
  return axios.delete(`${baseUrl}/${id}`)
}

export default { 
  getAll: getAll, 
  create: create, 
  update: update,
  delete: deletePerson
}
```

Comment: Just for the debugging purpose can you try calling your put method from other clients like postman and see if it changes. That way we can be sure that where the issue is.

Comment: @MilanPatel I use postman and the error was saying unknown endpoint

Comment: 0


Try using axios.post while everything else remains the same

Comment: @SwiftDev I tried changing put to post in index.js and now the error saying PUT http://localhost:3001/api/persons/64044115a34cd08c8f01bd85 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Get in the habit of reading errors, don't ignore them. Look at your server logs and look at the API response in the Chrome network tab. You're calling `window.confirm` on the server side. There is no `window` object on server side JS.

Comment: @AndyRay I tried editing the data and look on network tab, there was the object id, initially it was pending but after i refreshed it now becomes canceled. on the payload tab, it was showing exactly the name and number that I've just inserted jst now

Comment: @AndyRay can't use `window` object in server side means in this case, window.confirm can't be used in index.js ?